# Got 502 Bad Gateway, Use AWS ALB with ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-alb, aws-acm

I use AWS ACM to create Certificate for my domain.

**ACM：**
[image]

And then I create ALB and add listener to HTTPS

**ALB：**
[image]

While I input domain in browser. I still got 502 Bad Gateway.

Does anyone know how could I fix this?

**Target Group：**
[image]

**Health Check：**
[image]

Comment: What is in there in your targets? Can you please post screenshot of the error?

Comment: @MohitKumar I add screenshot with my target group setting.

Comment: Your both of the targets are unhealthy. Your health check is looking for 200 status check at "/". Do check if your app is running or not on both of the instances.

Comment: @MohitKumar I have ssh to instances, and use curl https://127.0.0.1:443, I could get the static html. So I think it should health.